# Неверно отрабатывает getLineCount

Tags: android, textview

Собственно, проблема такая: есть `ViewHolder` в `RecyclerView`. (Для лучшего понимания, убран лишний код)

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    @BindView(R.id.memeText) TextView memeText;
    @BindView(R.id.textExpandButton) TextView textExpandButton;

    private View view;
    private AdapterEventListener adapterEventListener;
    private Meme meme;

    @OnClick(R.id.textExpandButton)
    void onExpandClick(){
        memeText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        textExpandButton.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    void setData(Meme meme){
        this.meme = meme;
        setLongTextExpand();
    }

    private void setMemeText(String text){
        if(!FieldsValidator.isStringEmpty(text)){
            memeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            memeText.setText(text);
        }else{
            memeText.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setLongTextExpand(){
        Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "memeText line count in FeedAdapter = " + memeText.getLineCount());
        memeText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        if(memeText.getLineCount() > 5){
            textExpandButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            memeText.setMaxLines(5);
            Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "(memeText.getLineCount() > 5 in FeedAdapter");
        }else{
            Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "(memeText.getLineCount() < 5 in FeedAdapter");
            textExpandButton.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

    }

    ViewHolder(View view, AdapterEventListener adapterEventListener){
        super(view);
        this.adapterEventListener = adapterEventListener;
        this.view = view;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    }
```

В логи выводятся следующие значения:

```
D/TestingTag: memeText line count in FeedAdapter = 0
D/TestingTag: (memeText.getLineCount() < 5 in FeedAdapter
D/TestingTag: memeText line count in FeedAdapter = 0
D/TestingTag: (memeText.getLineCount() < 5 in FeedAdapter
```

Хотя, вот что рисуется в `RecyclerView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соот-но в логи должны выводится значения 1 и 1 соответственно у `memeText Line Count`. Куда закралась ошибка? При том я точно помню, что вчера все работало нормально с таким же кодом..

**UPD:** Важно отметить, что дальше идут логи, где `lineCount` ТОЛЬКО 1 или 0. Т.е. даже если у меня строка из 15 строк, все равно `lineCount` = 1.

Comment: Покажите bind метода адаптера точней ViewHOlder... onBindViewHolder, в этом куске кода что у вас - невозможно дать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

setMemeText не вызывается, текст в memeText не сеттится, поэтому количество строк  = 0, а скриншот, видимо, вчерашний, когда текст сеттился